# Одно- и двухсоставные предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Чем отличается односоставное предложение от двухсоставного?

Answer (score 1):

В односоставном предложении есть только один главный член: подлежащее или сказуемое, а в двусоставном и подлежащее, и сказуемое.
"Зимняя ночь." — односоставное.
"Настала зимняя ночь." — двусоставное.
Прочитайте в учебнике о видах односоставных предложений.